# grunt not recognized by Hudson build server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, hudson

I am trying to integrate my grunt build into our hudson build process. After installing node and grunt onto the Hudson server, I had to create a directory `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm` in order to get npm to install. Now after I run npm install (and it shows grunt was installed successfully) I get the error `grunt is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

When i type 'grunt' into the cmd directly on the machine I get the usual, no local grunt message so I should at least get that right?

Could this have something to do with it being run as the system profile? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem appears to be that wherever `grunt` was installed is not configured appropriate in your `PATH` system variable on the build server. Once that is included on the build-server, you should restart Hudson for it's instance and it's workers are aware of the new environment variable.

Comment: oh ok that makes sense.. I think I just need to reset the server to have it reload its PATH. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know how that works out for you and/or if you come across any problems.

Comment: I actually had no luck with that. I think installing globally does not include the "system" user. If I run where grunt while logged into the server, I see it at `C:\Users\Troy\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt`. If i understand correctly the system equivalent to this would be `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt` however that npm folder is empty. I do see files in C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Comment: When you are logged in as the Hudson user, are you able to run `where grunt` and `echo %PATH%` and see the location of the `grunt.cmd` file?